# Provide open-with option to user

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I am writing a file system application in the electron. When the user right clicks on file, I want to show a list of supported applications which can open the file as happened in OS platform.

If this technically possible with electron framework or any other framework provides this kind of feature.

Comment: any reason for downvoting? i have no knowledge of technical possiblities of this in electron.

Comment: this should be in the electron repo as a feature request not here. https://github.com/electron/electron